# Saving a new product into database using Kendo UI Grid

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I created a Create `Action` in `Controller` for saving new product into database. I saved it already but when I click `Refresh` button, it didn't save on Kendo Grid, either database.

```
public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ProductDTO> products)
         {
             var results = new List<ProductDTO>();

             if (products != null && ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 foreach (var product in products)
                 {
                     var create = db.Products.First(c => c.ProductID == product.ProductID);
                     results.Add(product);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                 }
             }
            return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
         }
```

**EDIT**

Kendo View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Products")
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Command(p => p.Edit()).Width(170);
        c.Bound(p => p.ProductID);
        c.Bound(p => p.Name);
        c.Bound(p => p.ListPrice);
        c.Bound(p => p.ProductNumber);
        c.Bound(p => p.Color);
        c.Bound(p => p.StandardCost);
        c.Command(p => p.Destroy()).Width(100);
    }
    )
    .ToolBar(tb => 
    {
        tb.Create();
        tb.Save();
    })
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)

            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
    .Sortable()        
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(d => d  .Ajax()
                        .Batch(true)
                        .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(c => c.ProductID);
                                    })
                        .Create("Create", "Home")
                        .Read("GetSub","Home")
                        .Update("Edit", "Home")
                        .Destroy("Delete", "Home")
                        .PageSize(10)
    )

    .HtmlAttributes(new { style= "width: 800px" })
)
```

What's a solution could be solve in this case? Thank you for your reply, have a great day!

Comment: Try to debug and see if your products is null when passing it.

Comment: please show your kendogrid view.

Comment: @Jaimin I've added Kendo view, would you please take a look at it?